# Fourier transform $\left[\mathrm{csch}(x+i\epsilon-t)\right]^n\left[\mathrm{csch}(x+i\epsilon+t)\right]^m$

Tags: physics, fourier-transform, complex-integration, hyperbolic-functions

In a physics related problem, I am trying to compute the Fourier transform
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{\sinh^{n}\left[\pi T_R\left(x+ i\epsilon-t\right)\right]\sinh^{m}\left[\pi T_L\left(x+i\epsilon+t\right)\right]}\right]\left(\omega\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt e^{i\omega t}}{\sinh^{n}\left[\pi T_R\left(x+ i\epsilon-t\right)\right]\sinh^{m}\left[\pi T_L\left(x- i\epsilon+t\right)\right]},
\end{align}
where $T_{L,R}$ are constants and $n,m$ are natural numbers. Employing the convolution theorem, we may split the Fourier transform as
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{\sinh^{n}\left[\pi T_R\left(x+ i\epsilon-t\right)\right]\sinh^{m}\left[\pi T_L\left(x- i\epsilon+t\right)\right]}\right]\left(\omega\right)=\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{\sinh^{n}\left[\pi T_R\left(x+ i\epsilon-t\right)\right]}\right]\left(\omega-\omega'\right)\ast\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{\sinh^{m}\left[\pi T_L\left(x- i\epsilon+t\right)\right]}\right]\left(\omega'\right),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 \left(f*g\right)\left(\omega\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega' f\left(\omega-\omega'\right)g\left(\omega'\right).
\end{align}
Therefore, we have to compute the Fourier transforms of each one separately. This was my idea, but it seems impossible to compute the total convolution [since the Fourier transform of $\left(\mathrm{csch}x\right)^n$ is a Euler Beta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587622/fourier-transform-of-1-sinhnx-mathrmi-epsilon). Any ideas (maybe different from this one) on how to proceed?